# Changing passwords via Python for SSL certificate

Tags: python, openssl

I am looking for a method of doing the equivalent of the command below using Python:

```
openssl rsa -aes256 -in serverKey.pem -out newkey.pem
```

I am trying to find out if this is possible in Python since Python meets my cross platform requirements and find a Python built in! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but I'm pretty sure the subprocess (more info available at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html ) module is best due to it being intended as a replacement for older ways of doing this such as `os.system()`. 
For me, if I don't need to capture output and want to keep things looking clean, I use `subprocess.call()`. You can check for OS using `sys`

```
import subprocess
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    cmd  = "windows alternative command"
else:
    cmd = "openssl blah"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a Cross platform method.  Hopefully a built in.  I don't believe that openssl is available on Windows.

Comment: @Keith ah I understand now. The code I posted is for running command-line commands - if you figure out a way to do it on windows I will update my answer to use the correct command on Windows